# Can't change font in Flex - Spark RadioButton

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript

I am trying to change the font size and family of a spark Radiobutton I create in run time:

```
            var radio:RadioButton = new RadioButton;

            radio.layoutDirection = "rtl";

            var format:TextFormat = new TextFormat();
            format.font = "Tahoma";
            format.color = 0x336699;
            format.size = 13;

            radio.setStyle("embedFonts", true);
            radio.setStyle("textFormat", format);

            radio.label = text;

            radio.groupName = "radiogrp_" + index.toString();
            hgrp.addElement(radio);
```

No matter what I try, the font stays the same. Both family and size remain default.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Define a nice `TextFormat` and then use it with `setStyle`:

```
attribFormat = new TextFormat(null, fontsize, 0x000000, null, null,null,null,null,"left");
myRadio.setStyle("textFormat", attribFormat);
```

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
var radio:RadioButton = new RadioButton;

radio.layoutDirection = "rtl";

radio.setStyle("embedFonts", true);
radio.setStyle("fontFamily", "Tahoma");
radio.setStyle("color", 0x336699);
radio.setStyle("fontSize", 13);
```

Comment: Also, the font size did not change.

Comment: Try to remove radio.setStyle("embedFonts", true);

Comment: Hi Anton, I rmoved the ebmebFonts and still the label is invisible.

Answer (score 0):

I try this it works

```
var radio:RadioButton = new RadioButton();
radio.addEventListener(FlexEvent.CREATION_COMPLETE, onRadioAddHandler);

radio.label = "Some text";
radio.x = 200;

this.addElement(radio);
```

Handler

```
private function onRadioAddHandler(event:Event):void {
    var radio:RadioButton = RadioButton(event.target);

    radio.layoutDirection = "rtl";

    radio.setStyle("fontFamily", "Tahoma");
    radio.setStyle("color", 0x336699);
    radio.setStyle("fontSize", 25);
}
```

Comment: Sorry, this does not work. I tried this and the fonts do not show, the label is empty.

Comment: You use mx RadioButton or spark? Maybe show all your code, all Application tag.